# Errors related to MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

These are the errors related to `MainActivity.java`:

1. Cannot resolve symbol 'helloworld' :6
2. ';' expected :6
3. 'class' or 'interface' expected :6
4. Expression expected :15

Line 6 is the "`import com.example.amedina.helloworld*;`" This is the code:

```java
package com.example.amedina.helloworld;
    
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import com.example.amedina.helloworld*;
    
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String msg = "Android : ";
    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.example.tutorialspoint7.myapplication);
        Log.d(msg, "The onCreate() event");
    }
    
    /** Called when the activity is about to become visible. */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(msg, "The onStart() event");
    }
    
    /** Called when the activity has become visible. */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(msg, "The onResume() event");
    }
    
    /** Called when another activity is taking focus. */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(msg, "The onPause() event");
    }
    
    /** Called when the activity is no longer visible. */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(msg, "The onStop() event");
    }
    
    /** Called just before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(msg, "The onDestroy() event");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this name of your class import "helloworld*" ? It should be like "import com.example.amedina.helloworld.*;" Ignore quotations. :)

Comment: @user3458271 Thank you. Can you help me in Line 15? That's the `setContentView` part.

Comment: Replace line 6 with this `com.example.amedina.helloworld.R;`. And line 15 with this ` setContentView(R.layout.layoutfile)` assuming that your layout filename is `layoutfile.xml`.

Comment: @SovathnaHong the filename is `activity_main.xml`. Also, I tried your idea to put the letter `R` in the line 6. Now it says `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'`.

Comment: @Danielle What is the package value in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file? Whatever that is just replace it with `package.R;` at line 6. And line 15 `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

Comment: My recommendation for you is to familiar yourself with Java first or if you just get started go for Kotlin before you jump to Android development.

Answer (score 0):

**Line 6** remove `*`

**Line 15** should contain a resource `R.layout.layoutfile` not `com.example.tutorialspoint7.myapplication`

It would be best to refer to the Android developer page. The `setContentView()` is basic required knowledge.

Comment: Do I have to change `com.example.tutorialspoint7.myapplication` completely with `R.layout.layoutfile` or do I have to just combine them?

Comment: You define an XML file decribing your layout, which is stored in res/layout of your project directoy. After you have defined it, you may then refer to it by ```R.id.thelayoutxmlfile```. You have to refer to the basic android tutorial at the developer page. This is a preliminary crucial concept my friend.

Comment: It says `Cannot resolve symbol: 'thelayout'`. How to fix?

Comment: No, the layout is just a placeholder example name. You have to create a layout file and whatever you name that file will be the actual name. Refer to basic beginner tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp